# passing string query param to angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

how can i pass string query to params in angular4
to get this URL
http://localhost:3000/reviews?business_id=KNpcPGqDORDdvtekXd348w

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your question and show a part of your data. Have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router"
private router: Router, //the router variable should be added in the constructor

const route = "revews"
const params = {query: "superQuery"}
this.router.navigate([route, params])
```

Comment: ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.restaurantService.getRestaurant(params["business_id"]))
        .subscribe((restaurant) => {this.restaurant = restaurant; this.id = this.restaurant.business_id; },
            (reserrmsg) => {this.restaurant = null; this.restauranterrMsg = <any>reserrmsg; });
}

Answer (score 0):

if u want to do it directly in html, then try the following:

`<a [routerLink]="url" [queryParams]="param">link<\a>`

where,

`url: string = '/reviews';
param: object = {
  business_id: 'KNpcPGqDORDdvtekXd348w'
};`